# SQL - find average value by using two different tables

Tags: sql

I have to find the average ram size of a pc (from `pc_table`) for all those manufacturers (from `product_table`) that making printers.

`pc_table` have these columns: `model`, `speed`, `ram`

`product_table` have these columns: `model`, `manufacturer`, `typeOfProduct` (pc/printer)

I've wrote this code:

```
SELECT a.manufacturer, AVG(b.ram) AS avg_ram_size
FROM pc_table b, (SELECT manufacturer, model
                  FROM product_table
                  WHERE type='PRINTER') a
WHERE b.model = a.model
GROUP BY a.manufacturer;
```

but for some reason, the output table is just empty.

Note: every manufacturer making both Printers & PCs, but still my output is empty table (which is wrong).

I just started with SQL, thanks for your help.
(if any piece of info is missing, comment and i'll add it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the pc_table only includes information for pc manufacturers, but you want information about pc manufacturers *who also make printers*. If that's the case, I suggest something like:

```
SELECT p.manufacturer, AVG(pc.ram) AS avg_ram_size
FROM product_table p INNER JOIN pc_table pc 
 ON pc.model = p.model
WHERE p.manufacturer IN
 (
  SELECT p2.manufacturer
  FROM product_table p2
  WHERE p2.type='PRINTER'
 )
GROUP BY p.manufacturer
```

Also your current join syntax is very old, the current ANSI syntax would use an [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).